# I got #num! error in my formula I used in Excel. I would like to ask where I got an error and What should I do?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file that is populated with a lot of formulas. I am trying to populate the result by subtructing the latest value to the previous value and dividing the result given in the cell. Please see the photo below. As you can see, starting in row 6 i used the formula of:

```
         "=ABS(IF(F7<=LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),10),(F7-LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),9))/E7,IF(F7<=LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),9),(F7-LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),8))/E7,IF(F7<=LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),8),(F7-LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),7))/E7,IF(F7<=LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),7),(F7-LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),6))/E7,IF(F7<=LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),6),(F7-LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),5))/E7,IF(F7<=LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),5),(F7-LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),4))/E7,IF(F7<=LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),4),(F7-LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),3))/E7,IF(F7<=LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),3),(F7-LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),2))/E7,IF(F7<=LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),2),(F7-LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),1))/E7,IF(F7<=LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),1),(F7-LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),1))/E7*(F7-LARGE(IF(find3=$H7,$F$6:$F$196),2))/E7)))))))))))"
```

In order to get the result of =(f7-f6)/e7. I added if functions cause there are some values that the lookup value is mentioned ($H7) below the table. When the lookup function was changed (please see the second photo), the formula was changed also into this:

```
          "=ABS(IF(F15<=LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),10),(F15-LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),9))/E15,IF(F15<=LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),9),(F15-LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),8))/E15,IF(F15<=LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),8),(F15-LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),7))/E15,IF(F15<=LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),7),(F15-LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),6))/E15,IF(F15<=LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),6),(F15-LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),5))/E15,IF(F15<=LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),5),(F15-LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),4))/E15,IF(F15<=LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),4),(F15-LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),3))/E15,IF(F15<=LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),3),(F15-LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),2))/E15,IF(F15<=LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),2),(F15-LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),1))/E15,(F15-LARGE(IF(find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196),2))/E15))))))))))"
```

But I've got a result of a #num! error. It's the same statement, the only difference is the looked up value. And when I try to show the calculation steps (Please see the third photo attached below), it says I've got an error in the first statement but why it was working on the first lookup value?

I am noob in excel. Please help me!!!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is “find3”?

Comment: I 'defined name' the range of $C$6:$F$196 into "find3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error is that the `LARGE` function returns `#NUM` because the underlying array is empty / contains the `FALSE` result from your `IF` function (see here for details https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/large-function-3af0af19-1190-42bb-bb8b-01672ec00a64).

The reason here likely is that your `find3=$C15,$F$6:$F$196` does not find a match.
Since we do not know what find3 is, you will need to look into the reason for that on your end (i.e., is there value of 5725 EGJ in your find3 data range? If not, why not? If yes, are you sure it spelled the same way (no leading spaces)?).

Once that is fixed you should be good to go.

Comment: I 'defined name' the range of $C$6:$F$196 into "find3"

Comment: Do you have 10 (or more) results for 5725 EGJ in your file? While the IF function might find a match, the LARGE(x,10) means you are looking for the 10th value. If there are less than 10 values, LARGE returns an error.

Comment: ahh I see now. thank you! I forgot that one.